# Python losing control of subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm using a commercial application that uses Python as part of its scripting API. One of the functions provided is something called `App.run()`. When this function is called, it starts a new Java process that does the rest of the execution. (Unfortunately, I don't really know what it's doing under the hood as the supplied Python modules are `.pyc` files, and many of the Python functions are SWIG generated).

The trouble I'm having is that I'm building the `App.run()` call into a larger Python application that needs to do some guaranteed cleanup code (closing a database, etc.). Unfortunately, if the subprocess is interrupted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it aborts and returns to the command line without returning control to the main Python program. Thus, my cleanup code never executes.

So far I've tried:

1. Registering a function with atexit... doesn't work
2. Putting cleanup in a class `__del__` destructor... doesn't work. (`App.run()` is inside the class)
3. Creating a signal handler for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the main Python app... doesn't work
4. Putting `App.run()` in a Thread... results in a Memory Fault after the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
5. Putting `App.run()` in a Process (from multiprocessing)... doesn't work

Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to make the code more visible.

Comment: I this running on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `try: App.run() finally: cleanup()` doesn't work; you could try to run it in a subprocess:

```
import sys
from subprocess import call

rc = call([sys.executable, 'path/to/run_app.py'])
cleanup()
```

Or if you have the code in a string you could use `-c` option e.g.:

```
rc = call([sys.executable, '-c', '''import sys
print(sys.argv)
'''])
```

You could implement @tMC's suggestion using subprocess by adding 
`preexec_fn=os.setsid` argument (note: no `()`) though I don't see how creating a process group might help here. Or you could try `shell=True` argument to run it in a separate shell.

You might give another try to multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__=="__main__":
   p = mp.Process(target=App.run)
   p.start()
   p.join()
   cleanup()
```

Comment: the os.setsid was really a force-of-habit.  it would be worth testing without it.

Comment: @tMC see my comment above.. it seems that setsid does make a difference.

Comment: I tried doing the `subprocess.call` method by dynamically generating a Python script and calling that. For some reason, it doesn't run, even though it has a return code of 0. If I run the dynamically generated file from the command line (or Python interactive), it works fine though. Such weird behavior...

Comment: @jasonm76: I've updated the answer to clarify how you could run a Python script as a subprocess.

Comment: It works! I just wrapped the call command in a `try..except KeyboardInterrupt` statement and `Ctrl-C` causes the subprocess to exit gracefully followed by my cleanup code. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

This is just an outline- but something like this?

```
import os

cpid = os.fork()
if not cpid:
    # change stdio handles etc
    os.setsid() # Probably not needed
    App.run()
    os._exit(0)

os.waitpid(cpid)
# clean up here
```

(os.fork is *nix only)

The same idea could be implemented with `subprocess` in an OS agnostic way.  The idea is running `App.run()` in a child process and then waiting for the child process to exit; regardless of how the child process died.  On posix, you could also trap for SIGCHLD (Child process death).  I'm not a windows guru, so if applicable and `subprocess` doesn't work, someone else will have to chime in here.

After `App.run()` is called, I'd be curious what the process tree looks like.  It's possible its running an `exec` and taking over the python process space.  If thats happening, creating a child process is the only way I can think of trapping it.

Comment: This seems close to something that might work.. When I tried it, I could hit Ctrl-C and get to the cleanup code, but the App.Run() process continuously restarted! I'm not familiar enough with the *nix commands to know what is going on though.

Comment: If you didn't put any loops in your python code; the loop must be in the App.run() code.  When the app is running, does the python process that called it still exist? `ps fax` will print the process tree.  If not, the app code called `exec` and consumed your python process space.  If that happens, you have little recourse or influence in what the app does. (short of sending it signals)

Comment: The `ps fax` command is really useful. From what I can gather, if I don't use `setsid`, when I hit `Ctrl-C` the App object generates messages indicating that it received TWO stop signals before aborting. When I use `setsid`, `Ctrl-C` kills the Python thread and the forked thread runs on its own, but it can't receive `Ctrl-C` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to wrap the App.Run() in a Try/Catch?

Something like:

```
try:
    App.Run()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print "User requested an exit..."
cleanup()
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your code... unfortunately it's the same result as my other tests: Exit immediately to the command line with nothing printed.

Comment: Bummer, I thought that would do the trick for you. Your App.Run() must be doing something nasty to bring down the Python process as well.